# QGIS drag-and-drop forms: move cursor to other field without mouse

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-custom-function

When I create a form by 'drag and drop' design, the only way to go to another field is by mouseclicking in that field.

Is it possible to do the same action with the tab-button, as it does in an autogenerated form?

(QGIS 2.18.7, Windows 10)

Comment: what version of QGIS, and what Operating System? Just tried on QGIS 2.18.3/Ubuntu and tabbing seems to work (even if using groups)

Comment: I'm using qgis 2.18.7 on windows 10

Comment: Can confirm it also works for QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit.